# How to use the startswith function to produce output like in the diff tool?

Tags: python, python-3.x, diff

Please help me solve (I think interesting) algorithmic problem. I spent (lost) the whole day today to solve this. Here is my code:

```
rman_config = ('''CONFIGURE RETENTION POLICY TO REDUNDANCY 1; # default
CONFIGURE BACKUP OPTIMIZATION OFF; # default
CONFIGURE DEFAULT DEVICE TYPE TO DISK; # default
CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP OFF; # default
CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP FORMAT FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO '%F'; # default
CONFIGURE DEVICE TYPE DISK PARALLELISM 1 BACKUP TYPE TO BACKUPSET; # default
CONFIGURE DATAFILE BACKUP COPIES FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO 1; # default
''')

rman_new_parameters = [('RETENTION POLICY', 'TO RECOVERY WINDOW OF 2 DAYS'),
                       ('CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP FORMAT FOR DEVICE TYPE', 'DISK TO controlfile_%F'),
                       ('CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP', 'ON'),
                       ('DEVICE TYPE', 'DISK PARALLELISM 4 BACKUP TYPE TO BACKUPSET')]

tuple_to_search = tuple([i[0] for i in rman_new_parameters])

for line in rman_config.splitlines():
    if line.startswith(tuple_to_search, 10):
        print('-  ' + line)
        print('+  CONFIGURE ' + '[parameter] ' + '[new value]' + ';')
    else:
        print('   ' + line)
```

Where:

- `rman_config` - variable with the default configuration
- `rman_new_parameters` - new parameters in random order to override defaults where:

  - first element in the tuple is a parameter (i.e. `CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP`)
  - second element in the tuple is a new value (i.e. `ON`)

So far I have this output:

```
-  CONFIGURE RETENTION POLICY TO REDUNDANCY 1; # default
+  CONFIGURE [parameter] [new value];
   CONFIGURE BACKUP OPTIMIZATION OFF; # default
   CONFIGURE DEFAULT DEVICE TYPE TO DISK; # default
-  CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP OFF; # default
+  CONFIGURE [parameter] [new value];
-  CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP FORMAT FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO '%F'; # default
+  CONFIGURE [parameter] [new value];
-  CONFIGURE DEVICE TYPE DISK PARALLELISM 1 BACKUP TYPE TO BACKUPSET; # default
+  CONFIGURE [parameter] [new value];
   CONFIGURE DATAFILE BACKUP COPIES FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO 1; # default
```

But I want this (like in `Diff`):

```
-  CONFIGURE RETENTION POLICY TO REDUNDANCY 1; # default
+  CONFIGURE RETENTION POLICY TO RECOVERY WINDOW OF 2 DAYS;
   CONFIGURE BACKUP OPTIMIZATION OFF; # default
   CONFIGURE DEFAULT DEVICE TYPE TO DISK; # default
-  CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP OFF; # default
+  CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP ON;
-  CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP FORMAT FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO '%F'; # default
+  CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP FORMAT FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO cf_%F;
-  CONFIGURE DEVICE TYPE DISK PARALLELISM 1 BACKUP TYPE TO BACKUPSET; # default
+  CONFIGURE DEVICE TYPE DISK PARALLELISM 4 BACKUP TYPE TO BACKUPSET;
   CONFIGURE DATAFILE BACKUP COPIES FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO 1; # default
```

The `startswith` function is great, but it doesn't tell me which tuple is recognized (returns only True or False). **My problem with above code is how to map following line:**

```
if line.startswith(tuple_to_search, 10):
```

**if it's True to the `rman_new_parameters` list.**

I haven't got a clue how to resolve it? I will be really grateful for any help.

Comment: Have you considered [`difflib.SequenceMatcher`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher)?

Comment: @kojiro No. So far, I wanted to try to solve it by hand and without using another library.

Comment: OK, but there's a lot to be said for learning by reading how the wheel was already implemented, too. ;)

Comment: @kojiro You're right. After your comment I quickly checked the ```difflib``` library, but unfortunately it does not meet my requirements for clear output. Output from functions in the ```difflib``` is little messy, so I prefer below solution by @Oleh.

Answer (score 2):

```
for line in rman_config.splitlines():
    for params in rman_new_parameters:
        if line.startswith(params[0], 10):
            print('-  {}'.format(line))
            print('+  CONFIGURE {} {}'.format(*params))
            break
    else:
        print('   {}'.format(line))
```

Basically, I didn't pass a tuple to `.startswith`, just tested one by one in a loop.

Also, [`for`+`else`](http://docs.python.org/dev/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops).

Comment: Thank you Oleh for your effort! For now, I will not give the "_accepted answer_" for your answer. Maybe in a few days someone will propose a solution using tuple and ```startswith``` function.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to do. But anyway I write the code. See if this answer matches your question. The main difference is your `if-else` block becomes `try-except` block. And the point is `index` function which returns the position of the first occurrence of the parameter in `tuple_to_search` here. I assume all value of parameters in `rman_new_parameters` is changed from `rman_config`.

```
rman_config = ('''CONFIGURE RETENTION POLICY TO REDUNDANCY 1; # default
CONFIGURE BACKUP OPTIMIZATION OFF; # default
CONFIGURE DEFAULT DEVICE TYPE TO DISK; # default
CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP OFF; # default
CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP FORMAT FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO '%F'; # default
CONFIGURE DEVICE TYPE DISK PARALLELISM 1 BACKUP TYPE TO BACKUPSET; # default
CONFIGURE DATAFILE BACKUP COPIES FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO 1; # default
''')

rman_new_parameters = [('RETENTION POLICY', 'TO RECOVERY WINDOW OF 2 DAYS'),
                       ('CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP FORMAT FOR DEVICE TYPE', 'DISK TO controlfile_%F'),
                       ('CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP', 'ON'),
                       ('DEVICE TYPE', 'DISK PARALLELISM 4 BACKUP TYPE TO BACKUPSET')]

tuple_to_search = [i[0] for i in rman_new_parameters]

for line in rman_config.splitlines():
    try:
        index = [line.startswith(tup, 10) for tup in tuple_to_search].index(True)
        print('-  ' + line)
        print('+  CONFIGURE ' + " ".join(rman_new_parameters[index]) + ';')
        #Add these if you don't need to check parameter once matched.
        #del rman_new_parameters[index]
        #del tuple_to_search[index]
    except:
        print('   ' + line)
```

output:

```
-  CONFIGURE RETENTION POLICY TO REDUNDANCY 1; # default
+  CONFIGURE RETENTION POLICY TO RECOVERY WINDOW OF 2 DAYS;
   CONFIGURE BACKUP OPTIMIZATION OFF; # default
   CONFIGURE DEFAULT DEVICE TYPE TO DISK; # default
-  CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP OFF; # default
+  CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP ON;
-  CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP FORMAT FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO '%F'; # default
+  CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP FORMAT FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO controlfile_%F;
-  CONFIGURE DEVICE TYPE DISK PARALLELISM 1 BACKUP TYPE TO BACKUPSET; # default
+  CONFIGURE DEVICE TYPE DISK PARALLELISM 4 BACKUP TYPE TO BACKUPSET;
   CONFIGURE DATAFILE BACKUP COPIES FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO 1; # default
```

**P.S.**

My output is bit different with your desired output(2 lines differ). I don't know why. So please ensure it is your desired output.

Yours:

```
...
+  CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP FORMAT FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO cf_%F;
...
   CONFIGURE DATAFILE BACKUP COPIES FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO 1; # default
```

Mine:

```
...
+  CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP FORMAT FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO controlfile_%F;
...
   CONFIGURE DATAFILE BACKUP COPIES FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO 1; # default
                                                                        ^
                                                                    no space here
```

Comment: This solution is not better than mine in any aspect. Much worse, in fact, because it tries to match everything (without short-circuiting), and then also looks through the unneeded list. It suppresses exceptions. Not to mention it's unreadable.